# correct way to write if statement:

Tags: python, if-statement

This seems like a very basic question... But I can't think straight for some reason...

How do I write the following without copying the "else" statement twice?
(and without needing to put this in a function)

I wrote print("a") and print("b"), but it originally has 4-6 statements.

```
    if os.path.exists(new_output_folder) and os.path.exists(prev_output_folder):
        subdirs_lastrun = [os.path.basename(x[0]) for x in os.walk(new_output_folder)]
        subdirs_prevrun = [os.path.basename(x[0]) for x in os.walk(prev_output_folder)]
        
        if not "ref" in subdirs_lastrun and "ref" in subdirs_prevrun:
            print("a")
        else:
            print("b")

    else:
        print("b")
```

Comment: 'correct way'. What defines 'correct'? [ask] [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* just use a boolean value to decide the complex stuff that has to happen at the end, something like:

```py
do_a = os.path.exists(new_output_folder) and os.path.exists(prev_output_folder)
if do_a:
    subdirs_lastrun = [os.path.basename(x[0]) for x in os.walk(new_output_folder)]
    subdirs_prevrun = [os.path.basename(x[0]) for x in os.walk(prev_output_folder)]
        
    do_a = not "ref" in subdirs_lastrun and "ref" in subdirs_prevrun

if do_a:
    print("a")
else:
    print("b")
```

Obviously this becomes advantageous if (as you state) the a/b paths are more complicated that a simple print.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(True):
    if os.path.exists(new_output_folder) and os.path.exists(prev_output_folder):
            subdirs_lastrun = [os.path.basename(x[0]) for x in os.walk(new_output_folder)]
            subdirs_prevrun = [os.path.basename(x[0]) for x in os.walk(prev_output_folder)]
            
            if not "ref" in subdirs_lastrun and "ref" in subdirs_prevrun:
                print("a")
                break
    # else case
    print("b")
    break
```

Comment: I think you forgot "break" at the end of "print ("b") ".